Omnibox url formation and navigation in chromium
How do I stop the URL bar from showing Google searches instead of actual websites in chromium.
I'm trying to tinker with chromium build - not latest.
For instance if I search google for xyz.com it give google search but if "/" is written after the url ex. xyz.com/ omnibox treats it like a url.
I want to change this behavior, so if user enter a url without the slash instead of the google search it should navigate to the given website.
Can you help?
According to some sources I have tried to locate proper functions and files where the text is processed but i am confused.
Files:
"src\components\omnibox\browser\autocomplete_result.cc"
"src\components\omnibox\browser\omnibox_edit_model.cc"
"src\components\omnibox\browser\location_bar_model_util.cc"

